# Get String from Backgroundworker method passed to webbrowser control

Tags: c#, foreach, webbrowser-control

I am trying to figure out how to set a string to a public value from inside a method loop that is called by a background worker.

Basically I have a foreach loop that sets various string values, then parses them.  I have a specific if statement that evaluates the value set to a string. If that string = "stop", I want to set the value of the result string to the public value which can then be accessed by another form which is a webbrowser control.

I cannot figure out how to set the string to the public value.  Here is what I have right now:

main form:

```
 public string result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { result = value; }
    }
```

Then in the DoWork I call the method and inside the method is there the if statement evaluates the strings and calls the form which has the webbrowser control embedded.  In that form I have:

```
 private update updateform = null;

    public browser(Form callingForm) : this()
    {
        updateform = callingForm as update;
    }

 public browser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = updateform.result;


    }
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly... U want to set mainform's public property if the string equals "stop" from the browser form?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or problem is you don't know how to access the property of mainform?

Comment: If you don't want to use worker.completed, you need to Invoke your changes to the UI - backgroundworker operates on a different thread than your UI. Something like Invoke(new MethodInvoker(updatePageItem));

Comment: Inside the if statement checking the string for "stop", I used this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate to call browser using: browser = new browser(this); browser.Show();  but the browser form does not see the result string that was available in the backgroundworker

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to make changes in the GUI.

For example:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do calculation ...
    e.Result = resultString;      
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // check cancellation ...
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = e.Result;
}
```

See also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The challenge is the RunWorkerCompleted does not start because when the "Stop" is hit in the DoWork method, it doesn't stop the entire method, just that iteration of the loop.